# Upload Multiple Files (POST) __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to do a multiple file upload functionality but I've been getting the issue: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I was able to do it for uploading a single file or in my case an image.

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class images(models.Model):
    session = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='photoadmin/pictures')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from .models import images


class uploadImages(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = images
        fields = ('session', 'picture')
        widgets = {'picture': forms.ClearableFileInput(
            attrs={'multiple': True})}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import uploadImages
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'photoadmin/index.html')


class upload(FormView):
    form_class = uploadImages
    template_name = 'photoadmin/upload.html'
    success_url = 'photoadmin/upload.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = uploadImages(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                form.save()
            return self.form_valid(form)

        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

**Traceback**

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/photoadmin/upload
>
> Django Version: 2.2.5 Python Version: 3.7.3 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'photoadmin.apps.PhotoadminConfig'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "C:.virtualenvs\BusinessPhotoManagementApp-wSA_cSYW\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:.virtualenvs\BusinessPhotoManagementApp-wSA_cSYW\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users.virtualenvs\BusinessPhotoManagementApp-wSA_cSYW\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /photoadmin/upload Exception Value:
>   **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0):

> Hi looks like the issue was the name of my Model was not following
>   PEP8, I changed images for Images, made the migrations and the error
>   disappeared.